# How can I get Wolf's open-source AMD miner to work on Ubuntu?

Tags: mining-software

I have never compiled anything before and the steps on GitHub are too complicated for me. How can I get Wolf's open-source AMD miner to work on Ubuntu?

https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner

Edit: since it matters, this is for Ubuntu 16.04 with multiple RX 470 cards.

Comment: The answer to your question is both card dependent and Ubuntu version dependent. Can you modify your question to include your specific details?

Comment: Updated. Is that specific enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. There is a [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480) with amdgpu and Gnome on the kernel 4.4 (default kernel with ubuntu 16.04). So If you want to use Gnome, Install a new kernel before installing the drivers :  [example](http://sourcedigit.com/20718-linux-kernel-4-7-3-released-update-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu/)
2. Install [amdgpu-pro](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx#)
3. Install the latest [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)
4. Install required dependencies and tools: "sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev build-essential libjansson-dev"
5. Edit the Makefile : add "-I /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include" to the ligne that starts with "OPT"
6. Compil : run "make"
7. Edit xmr.conf : for the RX 480, rawintensity:960 and workersize:8 seems to give the best results
8. run "sudo ./miner xmr.conf"

Comment: I didn't have to update the kernel, but everything else was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Maybe it was a problem with gnome. Are you running any x windows manager ?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure what that is. I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu, uninstalled some bloat like LibreOffice, and followed your steps except #1.

Comment: OK. Answer Edited

Comment: What hashrate did you get with which card?

Comment: 614 h/s @ stock clocks for RX480 ref cards and RX480 Nitro+OC

Comment: as of 20161102 this doesn't work with the 16.4 driver (at least for me)

Comment: yes, I can confirm that I've tested the above using 16.4 vs 16.3 driver, and 16.4 causes stuff not to work for some reason. I was gonna provide 16.3 available for download, but it seems like the license [is all stupid](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/gpu-pro-eula).

Comment: I had to also add `-L/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to build. Lubuntu 16.04, and it works with the 16.4 driver for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Ubuntu or these GPUs to test but based on this [thread](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/8250/ubuntu-16-04-lts-rx-480-mining-ethereum-confirmed-working) for the GPU driver, this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/2thvm4/10_xmr_tip_anyone_can_tell_me_how_to_install_and/) about the CPU miner and the Github link, main steps would be:

1. download [amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-306809.tar.xz](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx#)
2. extract the compressed file.
3. go to that folder and now run the installation script "sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install"
4. run "aticonfig --od-enable"
5. download [source of the miner](https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner/archive/master.zip)
6. extract the archive and go to the directory
7. install required dependencies and tools: "sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev build-essential libjansson-dev"
8. run "make"
9. when build is finished without any error, configure "xmr.conf" file (index -1 being your CPU)
10. run the miner

Comment: I'll try these out and report my results. Thank you.

Comment: There is no aticonfig with the new amdgpupro

Answer (score 1):

Moroccon Engineer's answer above works with AMDGPU-Pro 16.50 and Ubuntu 16.04LTS but only if you also add `-L/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to the `OPT` section of the **Makefile** as described by Jolly Mort in his comment.