# Are there any pre-built Monero miners for Linux?

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining, linux, compile

I've been having problems compiling wolf's miners.
Are there any pre-built linux miners, and if not, what are the packages that I need to fully build his CPU and GPU miners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and in my experience you shouldn't rely on anyone trying to give you compiled resources.
For the CPU miner you would need at least "automake libcurl4-openssl-dev make", those are the names for Ubuntu.

For the GPU miner if you are using R9 cards you can use these instructions.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/50dzu7/questionany_guide_on_linux_gpu_ati_mining/d74eyip
 Those instructions are for Ubuntu 14.04 as the newer versions of Ubuntu only support the AMD pro drivers.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to build the CPU miner, thank you for the help. But for the GPU miner, I have a R7 250 so I am just going to attempt claymore's provided by HerrDrone.

Answer (score 6):

For **CPU** Miner on linux, you can check Yam releases here:

https://mega.nz/#F!UlkU0RyR!E8n4CFkqVu0WoOnsJnQkSg

And for **GPU** releases, you could try Claymore v9.1, available here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B69wv2iqszefdkVDNkxla3BCZHc

Note: Both are **closed source**.

Comment: The first link does not redirect to the "official" Yam mega !

Comment: True. Edited link on post!

Comment: I used YAM and I didn't like it very much, but I didn't know about claymore's gpu miner. I thought it was only on windows

Comment: Claymore's linux version is not maintained. He [lost the source code](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=638915.msg16070547#msg16070547)

Comment: However, that version should work for R7 & R9 cards. I hope Claymore releases his miner for Linux again.

Answer (score 3):

There is no pre-built linux pool miner provided by the core team. 
You can only solo mine with the official binaries.

For Wolf's CPU Miner, you need "libcurl4-openssl-dev make automake gcc"

For his GPU Miner, You can refer to [this SE question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1626/110)

Answer (score 1):

Most pools maintain a "Getting started" page which includes a list of available miners, as well as startup instructions. Links to binaries (or to announcement pages which old those, to reasonably enough ensure the link is from the original author) are included.

See for instance http://monero.crypto-pool.fr/#getting_started

Comment: Only binaries provided are for Windows.