# Are AMD cards easier to mine with than NVidia?

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-hardware

Performance/cost/efficiency aside: are AMD/ATI/Radeon cards easier to set up than NVidia cards? I've been trying to start mining using ccminer on Linux with my Nvidia card and it has been a nightmare. Is it less frustrating with other cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The AMD miner has been [crowdfunded](https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/2400/open-source-amd-miner-by-wolf0) whereas the [NVIDIA proposal](https://forum.getmonero.org/21/the-thread-cemetery/2355/improved-nvidia-mining-software) didn't get through.

You can see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-i-get-wolfs-open-source-amd-miner-to-work-on-ubuntu/1638) how to set up AMD miner for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

AMD Cards have been more popular than NVidia for mining. LAtest NVidia developments have changed the status quo tho. However, expect more variety of software available for AMD like forked miners, etc. Expect also larger hashrates for medium-to-high performance amd cards in comparison to their nvidia counterparts