# Mining on an old Radeon 5830 with xmr-stak

Tags: mining, gpu-mining

As the title suggests, I am attempting to run xmr-stak on Ubuntu 16.04.0.

Currently I am following a hodge-podge of instructions found [here](https://blog.taborkelly.net/cryptocurrency/2017/12/03/monero-mining-on-ubuntu-server-16.04.html), [here](http://jordaneunson.com/2017/12/how-to-compile-monero-miner-xmr-stak-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-i-get-wolfs-open-source-amd-miner-to-work-on-ubuntu).  I'm noticing an issue with dkm during the installation of amdgpu-pro.  Also, for whatever reason, clinfo will not locate my GPU.

Compiling is fine, but I believe my issue is finding a driver for the 5830.  However, I have noticed that amdgpu-pro does suppport my card.

Comment: I have a HD 6950 but with windows and I got it working with the 14.1 beta drivers and xmr-stak 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and above, the AMD Catalyst or fglrx driver (compatible with your card) is no longer supported by AMD, or in Ubuntu. The AMDGPU-PRO and AMD Blockchain BETA driver aren´t compatible with your card, finally, the opensource ones can´t be used for mining due to OpenCL.

So, one solution could be to try installing the fglrx driver on your system. [Here the reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) from **Ubuntu WIKI**.

Comment: I'm not married to the idea of 16.04 or Ubuntu. But I have two more questions - could I follow the tutorial seen [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243387) to install drivers for the GPU. Alternatively, do you know of a resource for a different distro?

Comment: The tutorial seems quite correct, you can follow that or try Windows as the user above said it works.

Comment: I'm not really a windows user.  I've been using Ubuntu and Arch for so long that I would feel weird going back, especially since I haven't touched windows since Vista.

Comment: @emka Latest Windows on my PC was XP, but on my rig I'm using Win 10 due to higher hash rate rather than Linux.